# my xm bar is not full but can't collect xm

Tags: ingress

What would cause a xm gauge to stop at 94% even when I am walking around so much xm?  I recently leveled up to level 2. I took over two portals. Then, I noticed that when I walked by XM it would only fill my gauge up to 94%

Answer (score 5):

Have you [verified your account](https://support.google.com/ingress/answer/4552654?hl=en), yet?

Unverified accounts have restrictions on them. Account verification removes restrictions on your account such as the cap on your maximum XM and the cap on your maximum inventory space.